# Passing data in segue from plist. Table view to Details View

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, segue

I want to pass data contained in plist from a table view to details view controller. I did it with hardcoded values, but when I'm using plist I have trouble passing it through the segue.

Here is my **Wine.h** class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name; //name of the wine
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *image; //image of the wine
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *information; // details for the wine
```

**RedWinesViewController.h** file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *wineList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *thumbnails;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *information;
```

**RedWinesDetailViewController.h** file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *information;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Wine *wine;
```

**prepareForSegue** located inside **RedWinesViewController.m** file

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRedWineDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RedWinesDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.wine.name = [self.wineList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.wine.information = [self.information objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //destViewController.wine.image = [self.thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Value is %@", destViewController.wine.name);
    }
}
```

**viewDidLoad** in **RedWinesDetailViewController**

```
self.title = self.wine.name;
NSLog(@"Name value is %@ - %@", self.title, self.wine.name);
```

At this point the values are null. What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Is destViewController.wine non-nil if you log it in prepareForSegue?

Comment: How is the detail controller supposed to get its Wine object? Do you need to pass it instead of name and information?

Comment: Via the wine property. I started out this way. I don't have to use it. If there is other way to pass the data I will use it.

Comment: But how do set this property? It seems like you should pass the Wine object, then let the detail controller extract the values like name and information.

Comment: Hmm I don't think i actually do set it ... Let me fiddle with the code and will update you.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. Could I (and how to) just pass name, information instead of object to the Detail?

Comment: It depends on what you want to display in the detail controller. If you just want the name and information, you could send those. To do that you will need string properties in your detail controller for name and information, and then populate your label and text view with those strings in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Why don't you just do `Wine *wineSelected = [Wine new];` `wineSelected.name =`, `wineSelected.information =`, then `destViewController.wine = wineSelected;`. There's no point to have a Wine object if you are going to ignore it. Create the object instead of trying to pass each value individually.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you for sticking around and helping me. It works :)

Comment: @LyricalPanda Now it seems so simple :) Thank you too.

Comment: If you wish write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @mtashev I've written a longer answer on how to clean your code using best practices. Please let me know if you have questions, I feel that this will help you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and simple answer is you need to construct a Wine object and pass it through to use it with your code. For example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRedWineDetail"]) {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      Wine *selectedWine = [Wine new];
      selectedWine.name = [self.wineList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      selectedWine.information = [self.information objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      RedWinesDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      destViewController.wine = selectedWine;
    }
}
```

However upon further review of your code, you are using three arrays! You can combine this down to one: `winesList`.

In `viewWillAppear` you should be doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < winesCount; i++)
{
  Wine *curWine = [Wine new];
  curWine.name = ;
  curWine.information = ;
  curWine.thumbnail = ;
  [self.winesList.addObject:curWine];
}
```

So you construct yourself an array of wines. Why do you do this though? Because in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can simply do:

```
{
   Wine *cellWine = [self.winesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.nameLabel.text = cellWine.name;
   cell.thumbnailImageView = cellWine.thumbnail;
   cell.informationLabel.text = cellWine.information;
}
```

And finally, in your prepare for segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRedWineDetail"]) {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      Wine *selectedWine = [self.winesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      RedWinesDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      destViewController.wine = selectedWine;
    }
}
```

See how you no longer need to use three different arrays? You don't need to make sure each have the same count, are ordered the same, etc. Create each `wine` object instead of storing all it's information in different arrays, then just store an array of the wine objects. It'll make your code a lot cleaner, more condense, less confusing, and less prone to bugs!